# Ball in pong style game not hitting paddles

Tags: python, pygame, collision-detection, collision, pong

Its not that it just doesn't work, but its really hit or miss. The code for finding if the ball is within the paddle x works Perfectly, but they y does not. I think it has something to do with the edges of the paddles or ball, and it passing into the paddle from outside of the paddle area, but please help, or at least not yell at me and call me stupid, thanks!

```
import pygame,sys,time,random

pygame.init()
width,height =1000,600
win = pygame.display.set_mode((width,height))
pygame.display.set_caption("Hello World")

p1 = 40
p1width = 100
p1score = 0

p2 = 560
p2width = 100
p2score = 0

speed = 4

ballvx=random.randint(1,2)
ballvy=random.randint(1,2)

ballx=300
bally=50

font = pygame.font.Font('CursedTimerUlil-Aznm.ttf', 100)
p1text = font.render(str(p1score), True,(255,255,255))
p1textRect = p1text.get_rect()
p1textRect.center = (width/2/2, 250)

p2text = font.render(str(p1score), True,(255,255,255))
p2textRect = p2text.get_rect()
p2textRect.center = (width/2+(width/2/2), 250)

while True:
    win.fill((0,0,0))
    #line
    pygame.draw.rect(win, (40,40,40), pygame.Rect(width/2-2, 0, 4, 600))
    
    #p1
    pygame.draw.rect(win, (255,255,255), pygame.Rect(p1, 550, p1width, 10))

    #p2
    pygame.draw.rect(win, (255,255,255), pygame.Rect(p2, 550, p2width, 10))

    #ball
    pygame.draw.rect(win, (255,255,255), pygame.Rect(ballx, bally, 20, 20))    

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if keys[pygame.K_a]  and p1-speed>=0:
        p1-=speed
    if keys[pygame.K_d]  and p1+speed<=width/2-p1width-2:
        p1+=speed
    if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]  and p2-speed>=width/2+2:
        p2-=speed
    if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]  and p2+speed<=width-p2width:
        p2+=speed
        
    ballx+=ballvx
    bally+=ballvy
    
    if ballx+ballvx>=width-20:
        ballvx*= -1
        ballx+=0.1
        bally+=0.1
        
        
    if ballx+ballvx<=0:
        ballvx *= -1
        ballx+=0.1
        bally+=0.1
    if bally+ballvy>=height-20:
        print(width/2)
        print(ballx)
        if ballx <= width/2:
            
            p2score+=1
            print("score")
        else:
            p1score+=1
            print("is this even running???") 

        bally = 50
        ballx = random.randint(200,800)
        ballvx=random.randint(1,2)
        ballvy=random.randint(1,2)
        

    if bally+ballvy<=0:
        ballx+=0.1
        ballvy*=-1
        bally+=0.1
    
    if ballx+ballvx in range(p1,p1+p1width) and  bally+20 + ballvy >=550 :
        ballvy*=-1
        ballx+=0.1
        bally+=0.1
    if ballx+ballvx in range(p2,p2+p2width) and  bally+20 + ballvy >=550:
        ballvy*=-1
        ballx+=0.1
        bally+=0.1


    time.sleep(0.01)
    
    p1text = font.render(str(p1score), True,(255,255,255))
    p1textRect = p1text.get_rect()
    p1textRect.center = (width/2/2, 250)
    win.blit(p1text, p1textRect)

    p2text = font.render(str(p2score), True,(255,255,255))
    p2textRect = p2text.get_rect()
    p2textRect.center = (width/2+(width/2/2), 250)
    win.blit(p2text,p2textRect)


    pygame.display.update()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ballx+ballvx in range(p1,p1+p1width)` does not do what you expect. The [`range`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range) function produces a sequence of integral values. Therefore, `x in range(a, b)` checks if `x` is exactly one of the integers in the range `[a, b)`. If `x` is a floating point number, it is not an integer in the range.

e.g.: `range(5, 8)` generates the sequence `5, 6, 7`. The integral number `6` is in this sequence. However, the floating point number `6.5` is not in this sequence.

If you want to check whether a floating point number `x` is in a range `[a, b]`, you must use the comparison operators (e.g. `a <= x <= b`):

```py
while True:
    # [...]

    if p1 <= ballx+ballvx <= p1+p1width and bally+20 + ballvy >=550:
        ballvy*=-1
        ballx+=0.1
        bally+=0.1
    if p2 <= ballx+ballvx <= p2+p2width and  bally+20 + ballvy >=550:
        ballvy*=-1
        ballx+=0.1
        bally+=0.1
```